# ssh config host limits

Tags: ssh, configuration, line, config

I have some problem with `~/.ssh/config.`
I have 300 hosts on which i need to get as root and not as me.
I wrote the script which is creating the config file for me, which gives me config file with four lines:

```
host *
    user me
host <here 300 hostnames seperated by space and in this same line all>
    user root
```

When I want to connect to any server through ssh I have got the message, that I have a 'bad configuration in line: 10' or '...line 6' :/

```
wc -l .ssh/config
```

gives me 4

Comment: It looks like there is some limit of the configuration line length? How long is the configuration line with 300 hundred hosts?

Comment: there is 2195 charachters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current OpenSSH should read up to [4096](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/readconf.c#L1700) bytes long lines. But versions before OpenSSH 7.5 were reading only 1024 bytes, which might not be enough ([commit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/61b8ef6a66efaec07e023342cb94a10bdc2254dc)).

You have two possibilities:

- Update to OpenSSH 7.5
- Strip the lines to shorter ones not exceeding 1024 characters, for example

  ```
  host <here first 100 hostnames seperated by space and in this same line all>
          user root
      host <here another 100 hostnames ...>
          user root
      host <here another 100 hostnames ...>
          user root
  ```

Comment: Yes,
we use OpenSSH_5.3 @work.
It explains a lot.
Thanks a lot for such quick help. 
All the best